# Sampling elements in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sample

I'm trying to do resampling of the elements of a data frame. I'm open to use other data structures if recommended, but my understanding is that a DF would be better for combining strings, numbers, etc.

Let's say my input is this data frame:

```
16  x  y  z  2
11  a  b  c  1
.........
```

And I'd like to build as output another data structure (I take, another df) like this:

```
16  x   y   z
16  x   y   z
11  a   b   c  
.........
```

I guess my main issue is the way to append the content, which is on columns df[,1:4].

Thanks in advance,            p.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear from your description, but your desired output implies that you want to duplicate columns `1:4` according to column `5`, this should do the job

```
df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), df[, 5]), -5]
#     V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1   16  x  y  z
# 1.1 16  x  y  z
# 2   11  a  b  c
```

Comment: Yes, that clever combination did the trick. It could also be done in a less elegant way with a for loop. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're starting with something like:

```
mydf
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# 1 16  x  y  z  2
# 2 11  a  b  c  1
```

Then, you can just use `expandRows` from my "splitstackshape" package, like this:

```
library(splitstackshape)
expandRows(mydf, count = "V5")
#     V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1   16  x  y  z
# 1.1 16  x  y  z
# 2   11  a  b  c
```

---

By default, the function assumes that you are expanding your dataset based on an existing column, but you can just as easily add a numeric vector as the `count` argument, and set `count.is.col = FALSE`.

Comment: Whaaat,  this is nice

Comment: @RichardScriven, it's essentially David's answer with a few other bells and whistles.... Maybe I should CW this....

Comment: I see that now.  Just reading the source

Comment: It just seemed like a common enough thing that people ask for, so I put it in a function :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sample with replacement `n` rows from `df` data frame:

`df[sample(nrow(df), n, replace=TRUE), ]`